# How do you get an object's position and rotation through script?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I'm working on a project that requires me to get some of the position and rotation values to give to an Arduino via pyserial, but after sifting through the Blender documentation I can't find how to get them through script.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can access an object's transformations through the relevant properties (location, rotation_euler -  for Euler XYZ rotations, and scale) this way:

```
>>> object.location
Vector((-2.609607696533203, -3.618044137954712, 1.8581657409667969))

>>> object.rotation_euler
Euler((-0.6668576598167419, 0.697817325592041, -1.8853096961975098), 'XYZ')

>>> object.scale
Vector((1.2768771648406982, 1.4246054887771606, 0.6418209075927734))
```

Do note though that these values represent the object origin. If your origin is not at the center of your object, you might get unexpected location values.

Move the origin to the geometry (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*) first on all your objects to avoid this.

Or pythonically:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
bpy.ops.object.origin_set( type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY' )
```

On a more general note though, I'd like to mention some great sources for documentation and examples for Blender python scripting that will help you find answers more quickly next time (since finding object location and other transformations is probably one of the most basic and best documented things you can do in scripting, I'm assuming you're not familiar with these sources):

[Blender API official documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/) (with useful search bar)

[Scripting quickstart document](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/info_quickstart.html)

[Blender python scripting Code Snippets and Cookbook](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets)

Answer (score 13):

I'd also suggest using to_translation for location and to_euler or to_quat for rotation

```
>>> C.object.matrix_world.to_translation()
Vector((-0.7104860544204712, -0.3396846354007721, -0.06676528602838516))

>>> C.object.matrix_world.to_euler('XYZ')
Euler((0.0, -0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')

>>> C.object.matrix_world.to_quaternion()
Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

especially if  you are using a constraints or similar to move / rotate any objects, or are being moved by the parent object etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is below:
`bpy.data.objects["name_object"].location = Vector((1,1,0)) #x,y,z`