# Export model transformation matrix

Tags: transforms

I need to know if there is a add-on or a built in function that could export (all)  objects model transformation matrix (the matrix that contains the models scaling, rotation and translation information)in one code.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is overly broad. As it is now, a simple save to a blend file already answers your question, as this contains all object transformation matrices. However, that's probably not the answer you're after. At least specify in what way you'd like the matrices to be exported.

Comment: [`Object.matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=matrix_world#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world)

Answer (score 2):

From my quick and superficial testing both 3Ds and Obj seem to apply transformations and discard that information. DXF discards it too.

Collada DAE however keeps transformation matrices non applied, and even keeps instancing information. That is if one object were linked to the other using the same object data that relationship is maintained.

FBX also maintains both transformation matrices and instance relationships

Comment: thank you MR Duarte,in fact Iam studying now the Mechatronics engineering and I'm about to graduate and i have a project idea to make a builder robot, i have found in the BLENDER program the ability to give me the transformation matrix which i need to start my project,but i think with python language there is a code can export all object transformation matrix can you help me with this code

Comment: Sorry I am no coder, my programing skills are very limited, I wouldn't be able to help if I wanted to. See if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/how-do-you-get-an-objects-position-and-rotation-through-script