# How can I swap two objects positions?

Tags: python, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

Either a script or addon or whatever, is there any easier way to swap the Z coordinates of two objects in one click or something, I am making a graph like animation and I need to swap the bars a lot, my current method takes forever, I jot down the Z coord for object 1 and then swap them, this is very slow and I feel like there should be an easier way.

You can actually look me up on YouTube I make graph animations, many other people use adobe after effects but I'm broke.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use script for it. *And so much example on the Internet.* Swapping two object coordinates values is a simple and easy task for script. You should try it yourself and if there is still any question after you find in stack exchange and Blender API, then ask another question about your try.

Comment: I dont know how this site works I got no email, anyway. Thanks Hikariztw, that was very unhelpful. I will pay someone to make a script/addon for me then, get in touch with me or you can just give me the script for free right here, that would also be awesome.

Comment: For script to retrieve coordinate of an object, see this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/how-do-you-get-an-objects-position-and-rotation-through-script