# How can I change the transform by minimal code?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I just want to set the location, rotation, and scale of the object.
I tried to get code by reverse engineering but when I moved, rotated, and scaled my object I saw complicated code.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to get exact code you shouldn't change transform in view port.
when you change the transform in this panel it works:

[image]

[image]

**Location**

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
obj.location = (0,0,0)
```

**Rotation**

```
import bpy
import math

obj = bpy.context.object
obj.rotation_euler = (0,math.radians(90),0)
```

**Scale**

```
import bpy

obj= bpy.context.object
obj.scale = (1,1,1)
```

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you I fixed it

Comment: AFAIC setting the matrix basis values absolutely (as above) and transforming are totally different.  These are showing only the resultant local transform. [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/how-do-you-get-an-objects-position-and-rotation-through-script) _eg_ rotating the cube in question image again around the view axis, or moving globally cannot be simply crunched into fields.  In the most part initial values can be set when the object is created.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you for sharing! I didn't see this post