# How to access to pivot location?

Tags: python

I just want to get the pivot location of the 3d model!

[image]

I tried to set the cursor to pivot position and print the cursor location

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
print(bpy.context.scene.cursor.location)
```

I had this error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects pivot around their origins, or (0, 0, 0) in their local space. An object's position is simply the location of its origin in world space. You can get this as a Vector from the object's location variable:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
print(obj.location)
```

If you actually did want to set the cursor location:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = obj.location
```

See [How do you get an object's position and rotation through script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/how-do-you-get-an-objects-position-and-rotation-through-script) for a more thorough look.

Comment: I know how to get the location of the object I just want to know is it possible to get the pivot location? because when I change the location of the object pivot will not change. pivot is a kind of local position am I right?

Comment: so If we convert the world position to the object position is it pivot location?

Comment: I re-wrote the first sentence of my answer, does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 3):

**Global and Local**

The scene cursor location is in global coordinates.

For an object `ob`

What you see in the location field of an object is its basis matrix translation.

```
ob.matrix_basis.translation # == ob.location
```

, Rarely for an object with parents and / or constraints will `ob.location` also be the global location of the origin of the object.  An object with `ob.location == (0, 0, 0)` can be globally anywhere in scene via  parenting or  a copy location constraint to another object.

Using  `ob.matrix_world.translation` will ensure global (or world) coordinates, hence to set the cursor location to the objects global location

```
scene.cursor.location = ob.matrix_world.translation
```

Be very wary of mixing the two. (global and local)